# How to make tkinter right click menu work on one widget only?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a simple way to get the right click menu to open on texty only and not the whole window?

This was a quick mashup to illustrate my question.  Inheriting from texty on line 25 was a shot in the dark, which didnt work, but it's close to a simple solution, like I am seeking.  I was hoping to avoid programming a whole class each time I want to set a right click menu.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def menu_popup(event):
    try:
        popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)        
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()

        
win = Tk()

win.geometry("600x550+125+125")

e = Entry(win, width=50, font=('Helvetica', 11))
e.pack()
e.insert(0, "Some text....")

label = Label(win, text="Right-click to see a menu", font= ('Helvetica 18'))
label.pack(pady= 40)

texty=Text(win, height=10)
texty.pack()

popup = Menu(texty, tearoff=0)
popup.add_command(label="New")
popup.add_separator()
popup.add_command(label="Open")
popup.add_separator()
popup.add_command(label="Close")

win.bind("<Button-3>", menu_popup)

button = ttk.Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.destroy)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget on which the callback should be executed for the respective event is determined by the widget you call `bind` on(and the level of bind too*). So if you want the event to be identified within `texty`, then apply binding to it.

```
texty.bind("<Button-3>", menu_popup)
```

* There is `bind_all` which executes no matter which widget has focus or is called upon. Read [54.1. Levels of binding](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/binding-levels.html) for more info.